# How do I make my Python exception class be raised without its full name?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

For reference, these are the custom exception classes for my package:

```py
class StaticvarException(Exception):
    '''
    Base class for staticvar exceptions.

    Args:
        message (str): error message.
    '''
    def __init__(self, message: str):
        super().__init__(message)


class UnsupportedTypeError(StaticvarException):
    '''
    Should be raised when a non-standarad type or an unsupported type is specified.

    Args:
        message (str): error message.
    '''
    def __init__(self, message: str):
        super().__init__(message)
```

When `UnsupportedTypeError` is raised, it gives its full name in the error message.

Example:

```
staticvar.exceptions.UnsupportedTypeError: my_method.counter: variable type must be a valid type or a generic type from the typing module. Type specified: an_invalid_type
```

What I want:

```
UnsupportedTypeError: my_method.counter: variable type must be a valid type or a generic type from the typing module. Type specified: an_invalid_type
```

I raise the error by specifying the message in the exception class, if that's relevant:

```py
error_msg = "..."
raise UnsupportedTypeError(error_msg)
```

What should I do?

**Edit:**
Could perhaps the way exception classes are imported have something to do with it?

Comment: You should probably construct your own error messages rather than just dumping the string representation of the exception object to the output.

Comment: Note that the fully qualified name is only produced when printing the *traceback*, not the exception itself.

Comment: @chepner Can you please tell me how to do that? Also, if I raise a `ValueError` in the same way I raise my own error (by specifying the error message as a string), it doesn't give me the full name of the ValueError, meaning that it's definitely implementable.

Comment: It is the full name; `ValueError` is bound in the built-in scope, not the scope of any module.

Comment: Huh. So it really might just have to do with the way the exceptions are imported. I'll answer my own post if I figure it out.

Comment: No, regardless of how you import the module, the full name of *your* exception will be the same. It's part of the definition of the traceback object, I believe, that's printing the full name of the exception.